# Orchard CMS: add image to custom Item

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

Hi once again :) My next question about Orchard CMS looks trivial but..

I have my custom NewsModule with `NewsItem`  type which consists of `TitlePart`, `BodyPrt`, and my custom `NewsPart`. `NewsPart` is based on `NewsPartRecord`.

Now I have to extend my `NewsItem` document type with Image. So far I found that there are `ImagePart` and `MediaLibraryPickerField`. 
`ImagePart` stores `width` and `heihgt` of image, so I think it is something for internal use.

The next one is `MediaLibraryPickerField`. After googling for a while, I found that I can extend my `NewsPart` using `WithField()` method. 
But! First question here: when I'm configuring `Page` type with Admin UI, I can add field to the `type`. But using `Migrations` I can't add field to `NewsItem`, only to `NewsPart`.

The second question here. MediaLibraryPicker allows me to select any type of file from library, image, text, zip or any other. And this is not what I actually need.

So, what are the best practices in Orchard to extend Items with icons?

thanks.

Comment: ok, when you add fields to `type` in Admin UI, orchard creates new `part` with the same name like `type`. so, the first question is resolved and I can add field only to `Part`

Comment: You should ask questions one at a time. Asking two is pretty much guaranteed to only give you answers to only one of your questions, and it makes the post less efficiently googlable.
The media picker field has a setting for limiting the media content types that can be selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can add fields to NewsItem, it just requires a different type of definition. It confused me too as it's not as intuitive as you'd like it to be.

To add parts you are using **AlterTypeDefinition**.

```
this.ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition(
    "NewsItem", 
    cfg => cfg.WithPart("NewsPart"));
```

But to add fields you have to also use **AlterPartDefinition** and specify the NewsItem not the NewsPart.

```
this.ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
    "NewsItem", 
    builder =>
        builder.WithField(
            "NewsImages", 
             fieldBuilder =>
                 fieldBuilder.OfType("MediaLibraryPickerField")
                 .WithDisplayName("News Images")
                 // Allow multiple images
                 .WithSetting("MediaLibraryPickerFieldSettings.Multiple", "true"))
```

Considering second question, MediaLibraryPickerField has option to display only selected types/parts.

```
.WithSetting(MediaLibraryPickerFieldSettings.DisplayedContentTypes="Document,Video")
```

If you need new media type you have to create new ContentType with Stereotype "Media", it also needs "MediaPart" and part that defines metadata for that type. You can look at how **Document** or **Video** is defined for sample code.

Comment: adding `MediaLibraryPickerField` to `part` is obvious of course, it wasn't the problem. In first part I asked about how to add field to `Type`, but I've already found that it  is impossible.

Considering second part, I haven't read about `DisplayContentTypes` before, so thanks a lot, seems it is exactly what I need.

Comment: what `DisplaydContentTypes` value should I use to filter images? tried `Image` but doesn't work. Can't find these in source code

Comment: You didn't understand me, you can add fields to `Type` through `AlterPartDefinition`. It's confusing by name, it can be used to add fields to type as well. Just don't put as first parameter name of the part, but name of the type aka "NewsItem". I don't know how else to put it.

Comment: Adding a field is not the problem. the problem is to allow user to choose only images from Media Library.

Comment: I wasn't aware DisplayedContentTypes isn't working. Created issue on this https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/21051